# Regex for rebuilding html tag

Tags: regex, spring-boot, regex-lookarounds, regexp-replace

I need to change some html tags inside of a document that are marked with a class named **highlighted**. I need a regex to find inside of this document for tags in this form **`(<a><span class="highlighted">VAL</span>)`** adjacent to similar ones and replace it with part of its content keeping the data inside of span and append it to the others found.

**Input**

```
<p>
 <a name='hl_1'></a><span id='hl_2_0' class="highlight">word1</span>
 <a name='hl_2'></a><span id='hl_3_1' class="highlight">word2</span>
 <p>Something in the middle that shouldn't change</p>
 <a name='hl_3'></a><span id='hl_4_0' class="highlight">word3</span>
 <a name='hl_4'></a><span id='hl_5_1' class="highlight">word4</span> 
 <a name='hl_5'></a><span id='hl_6_1' class="highlight">word5</span>
</p>
```

**Expected result**

```
<p>
    <a name='hl_1'></a><span id='hl_2_0' class="highlight">word1 word2</span>
    <p>Something in the middle that shouldn't change</p>
    <a name='hl_1'></a><span id='hl_4_0' class="highlight">word3 word4 word5</span>
</p>
```

I hope you understand my questions. To be honest I'm not really sure I can use Regex to perform this kind of complex operation but a friend suggested it, so that's why I need your help.

Thanks again guys.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags can't parse html with regex

Comment: You can parse HTML with regex. Don't let anyone convince you otherwise.

Comment: @RoboMop ok can you do what I want to do with regex?